# Insert a new line for each field in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I am working on the GUI in Java. I could not figure out how can I insert a new line for each field. Can anybody help me with this problem? Here is my code:

```
public class InsertPanel extends JPanel{
    public InsertPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(540, 500));

        JLabel isbnLabel = new JLabel("ISBN: ");
        JTextField isbnTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel authorLabel = new JLabel("Author: ");
        JTextField authorTextFld = new JTextField(10);  

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
        JTextField titleTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price: ");
        JTextField priceTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);

        add(isbnLabel);
        add(isbnTextFld);
        add(authorLabel);
        add(authorTextFld);
        add(titleLabel);
        add(titleTextFld);
        add(priceLabel);
        add(priceTextFld);
        add(submitBtn);
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Those fields in the output were on the same line. I want to them look like

ISBN:

Author:

Title:

Price:

Submit

TextArea:

Thank you very much!

Comment: FlowLayout and force a line break?

Comment: @JClassic: um, how about no.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `GridBagLayout`

Maybe something like...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
public class InsertPanel extends JPanel {

    public InsertPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.yellow);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel isbnLabel = new JLabel("ISBN: ");
        JTextField isbnTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel authorLabel = new JLabel("Author: ");
        JTextField authorTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
        JTextField titleTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price: ");
        JTextField priceTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        add(isbnLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(authorLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(titleLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(priceLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(isbnTextFld, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(authorTextFld, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(titleTextFld, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(priceTextFld, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(submitBtn, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = gbc.REMAINDER;
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), gbc);
    }

}
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details